# Can't add a new image to the same collection after deleting one or more records | Spatie Media

Tags: laravel

I am now trying a way to delete some desired images to be deleted from a model and add more in the future to the same collection as per the requirements in Spatie Media.

I tried the following to delete the media from the database record and filesystem. It works but I could not add new images to the same collection for the same model (in my case, it's organization). I tried adding images to a new organization for the same collection and it works. But again, if I delete one or a few of the images, I can't add new images for the same collection to the same organization model.

I want this because I am having a image gallery for each organization and they must have ability to add or delete as per their requirements.

```
if (count($idsToDelete) > 0) {
   $imageGalleryToDelete = $organization->media()
             ->whereIn('id', $idsToDelete)
             ->get();

     foreach ($imageGalleryToDelete as $image) {
         $image->delete();
     }
 }
```

```
if (count($idsToDelete) > 0) {
   $media = Media::whereIn('id', $idsToDelete)
             ->get();

     foreach ($media as $image) {
         $image->delete();
     }
 }
```